# How to show loading icon for XHR requests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a loading image that gets displayed on `$routeChangeStart` and is hidden once the route has changed.  I'm trying to find something like this that can be used with xhrStart and xhrSuccess.

```
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
        $rootScope.loading = true;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
        $rootScope.loading = false;
    });
```

I know I can do this:

```
$rootScope.loading = true;
$http.get('/api/customers').success(function(data) {
   $rootScope.loading = false;
   ...
```

but that gets tedious.

Is there an XHR event in angularJS that can be used to show/hide the loading image?

Comment: If the loading graphic is global, you can use an `httpInterceptor` for this.

Comment: The graphic is global on the `$rootScope`.  I'm reading the documentation now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the loading graphic is global, then you can solve this using an `httpInterceptor`.  This is a naive implementation of an interceptor that toggles `$rootScope.loading`:

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('LoadingInterceptor', function ($rootScope) {

        $rootScope.loading = false;

        return {
            request: function (config) {
                $rootScope.loading = true;
                return config;
            },
            response: function (response) {
                $rootScope.loading = false;
                return response;
            }
        };
    })
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('LoadingInterceptor');
    });
```

**Note:** You may encounter issues with this *naive* implementation.  For example you may have parallel XHR calls (and this implementation will cause the loader to flash).  This is because when the first call response occurs `$rootScope.loading` is set back to `false` (even when the second call is still in progress).